# *ngif not working if using subscribe in ngOnInit

Tags: html, angular, typescript

this is my component code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
//import { Item } from '../item/item.model';
import { CartItem } from './cart-item.model';
import { CartService } from './my-cart.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-cart',
  templateUrl: './my-cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-cart.component.css']
})
export class MyCartComponent implements OnInit {
  items:CartItem[];
  subscribe:Subscription;
  display=true;
  constructor(private cartService:CartService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscribe=this.cartService.itemsChanged.subscribe(
      (items:CartItem[])=>{
        this.items=items;
      });
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscribe.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

and this is my html code

```
<p *ngIf="display">my-cart works!</p>
```

if i removed the subscription from ngOnInit it works fine.
can any one help? I don't know why it doesn't work

Comment: any console errors? this.cartService.itemsChanged might be null?

Comment: no, there is no console errors

Comment: where are you emiting subject ????

Comment: What does itemsChanged do? Is it a function? A behaviorSubject?

Comment: there must be an error within your ngOnInit, because if the template only consists of the ngif und that propety is set to true, then everything looks fine. Add an if check into the subscribed value. only add it to this.items, if items is not falsy.

Comment: items change emmit the items list because i need to listen to every change on this list

Answer (score 0):

These two are irrelevant. Try this   display: boolean =true;